# Error when adding SeleniumLibrary into RED in eclipse

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to create a project with robot-framework. All my libraries are installed. The path to SeleniumLibrary is properly referenced in red in eclipse but it shows an error. When i check the details of the error this is what i get. Can someone help me fix this?

**Below is the description of the issue:**

Library specification generation problem

```
Problem occurred during generating libdoc for 'SeleniumLibrary' library located at '/Users/interview/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/__init__.py'.
Following exception has been thrown:
            Exception: Importing test library '/Users/interview/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary' failed: ImportError: cannot import name PY3
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/interview/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
                from SeleniumLibrary.base import DynamicCore, LibraryComponent
              File "/Users/interview/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/base/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
                from .context import ContextAware
              File "/Users/interview/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/base/context.py", line 17, in <module>
                from SeleniumLibrary.utils import escape_xpath_value
              File "/Users/interview/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/utils/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
                from .types import is_falsy, is_noney, is_string, is_truthy, PY3, WINDOWS
              File "/Users/interview/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary/utils/types.py", line 19, in <module>
                from robot.utils import PY3, is_truthy, is_falsy
            PYTHONPATH:
              /Users/interview/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/SeleniumLibrary
              /Users/interview/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
              /private/var/folders/k7/rp8r07gn3gndbwxvq7h1wjwr0000gn/T/RobotTempDir6873193002526746803
              /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-19.3.1-py2.7.egg
              /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
              /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
              /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
              /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
              /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
              /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
              /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
              /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
              /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
              /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
              /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
```

Comment: I think you need to focus on this part of the error: `ImportError: cannot import name PY3` What is your version of selenium library? Perhaps it could be a version mismatch, that's another think to check.

Comment: @pavelsaman the versions i am using are

`selenium==3.141.0`
`robotframework-selenium2library==3.0.0`
`robotframework-seleniumlibrary==4.4.0`
`robotframework==3.1.2`